# c pointers and array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int b[] = {0,0,0,0,0};
    int *p = b;

    for (int i =0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        b[i] = a[i]+1;
        *p = a[i]+1;
        p++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf (" %i \t %i \t %i \n", *p++, b[i], a[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For this code I get why the output for a and b but why does the pointer have the same value of a?

*p is b[0] = a[0]+1, isn't it? 
So p++ means next address over for b so it's b[1]=a[1]+1.

```
ie 
*p  b  a
1  2  1
2  3  2
3  4  3
4  5  4
5  6  5
```

Comment: You mislabeled your columns: it should be `*p b a`, not `a b *p`.

Comment: yeah i did , my bad. Fixed

Comment: For the sake of change-resistence, better do `int b[sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])] = {...` and replace the `5` values by the same term. This way, you can change the array `a` and everything will be ok.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are getting *undefined behavior*. At the end of the first loop `p` points to "one past the end" of `b`. Without resetting it, you then dereference it and continue to increment it, both of which cause *undefined behavior*.

It *may* be that on your implementation the array `a` is stored immediately after array `b` and that `p` has started to point into array `a`. This would be one possible "undefined" bahaviour.

Comment: so basically it can be anything, just in this case it appears to point to the next address in the memory in this case which it points to the starting element of array a? correct me if i am wrong. Thanks

Comment: exactly. it can be anything. The best case is that it crashes so you are aware something is wrong early.

Comment: @user2135885: To me it seems like a reasonable explanation although it is possible that there is a more obscure reason for the coincidence that you are seeing.

Answer (score 1):

after the first for{},p point at b[5],but the size of b is 5,so b[5] value is unknow,the printf *p is the same value as a[i],the reason may be in memory b[5] is a[0].

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need to do is to add a `p = p - 5;`

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void)
{
    int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int b[] = {0,0,0,0,0};
    int *p = b;
       int i =0;

    for (i =0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        b[i] = a[i]+1;
        *p = a[i]+1;
        p++;
    }
    p = p - 5;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf (" %i \t %i \t %i \n", *p++, b[i], a[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: better: `p = b` again, as the `5` might change.

Answer (score -2):

you shouldnt make seperate loop for printing and incrementing the values of the array . do both in same loop and do the follouwing to get ur output :)
    #include 
    #include

```
int main(void)
{

int a[]={1,2,3,4,5};
int b[]={0,0,0,0,0};
int c[]={0,0,0,0,0};
int *p;
int i;
p=c;
for( i =0 ; i<5 ; i++)
{
    b[i]=a[i]+1;
    *p=b[i]-1;
    //*p++;

//for( i =0 ; i<5 ; i++)

    printf(" %i \t %i \t %i \n" ,*p,b[i],a[i]);

}
return 0;
}
```