# i cannot find any error in my program but it is not giving desired output

Tags: c, printing, for-loop

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

int a[]={1,2,3,4,5};
int b[]={0,0,0,0,0};
int *p;
int i;
p=b;
for( i =0 ; i<5 ; i++)
{
    b[i]=a[i]+1;
    *p=b[i]-1;
    printf(" %i \t %i \t %i \n" ,*p,b[i],a[i]);

}
return 0;
}
```

i want the output as :

```
*p   b   a
 1   2   1
 2   3   2
 3   4   3
 4   5   4
 5   6   5
```

but it is displaying like :

```
*p   b   a
 1   1   1
 2   3   2
 3   4   3
 4   5   4
 5   6   5
```

even i am adding +1 in each a[]. but for the first printing it shows 1 output . why?

Comment: `*p=b[i]-1;` replaces the value of `b[0]` by `b[i]-1` everytime. So on the first loop with `i = 0` you're decrementing `b[0]`.

Comment: strangely familiar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15224892/c-pointers-and-array  must be a homework :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a working version of your program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

int a[]={1,2,3,4,5};
int b[]={0,0,0,0,0};
int c[]={0,0,0,0,0}; //another array
int *p;
int i;
p=c; // point p to a new array to write to.
for( i =0 ; i<5 ; i++)
{
    b[i]=a[i]+1;
    *p=(b[i]-1);
    printf(" %i \t %i \t %i \n" ,*p,b[i],a[i]);

}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The `p=b;` sets `p` to point to `b[0]`. So although `b[0]` is incremented by `b[i]=a[i]+1;`, it is decremented back by `*p=b[i]-1;`.

Comment: help me to get solution of it without creating next array

Answer (score 1):

The problem is:

```
int a[]={1,2,3,4,5};
int b[]={0,0,0,0,0};
int *p;
int i;
p=b; // <<---- HERE
```

you make `p` point to the first element of array `b`, then in this code:

```
b[i] = a[i]+1;
*p = b[i]-1;
```

Although you assign value `2` into the first element, `*p = b[i]-1;` rewrites it with `1` again, which is the reason why the first line of your output is:

```
1 1 1
```

Comment: how can i remove this error without creating another array ?

Answer (score 1):

The key is setting p=b. Both p and b are pointers, which means that both *p and b[0] refers to the same data.

In the first iteration in the loop you first add one to b[0] and then you subract one. For the following iterations *p is still the same as b[0] but the value is taken from higher indices.